# Браузер не читает фоновое изображение

Tags: java, html, css, spring

Привет я хочу поставить фоновое изображение своему сайту. Но браузер не читает его
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вроде путь к картинке сделал правильным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>


        <title>Home Page</title>





<body>
<body class="bg-full">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">School</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Наш университет</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Электронный журнал</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Студенты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Карьера</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="container">

</div>


<div class="bg">
    <div class ="pokaz">
        <form action="allStudents" method="post">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Web XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <location>/errors</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой style.css

```
bg-full { 
    background-image: url('../../images/home.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%; }


.bg{
    background-color: black;
}
.it{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}


.pokaz{

   margin: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 


}

.add{
   width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: если в боаузерной строке обратиться к файлу он по этому пути откроется?

Comment: нет, может я не правильно что то сделал

Comment: очевидно да, ресурсы не раздаются, необходимо добиться чтобы открывалось, т.е. проблема не в коде

Comment: А в чем может быть

Comment: web xml покажите и я не очень догоняю структуру проекта пока, по скрину сложно

Comment: Добавил веб XML

Comment: попробуйте туроиал из ответа тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg-full{
  background-image: url("../images/home.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-full"><body>
```

Если у вас есть структура папок:

`* Web-XML/views
  * index.jsp
* images/
  * home.jpg`

то код `CSS` должен быть

`html{
  background-image: url("../images/home.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}`

`../` в URL поднимается на один уровень вверх в структуре каталогов. Здесь он может найти папку images. Затем он находит изображение home.jpg

Comment: Получается просто только URL поменять? я поменял все так же

Comment: тогда добавте ещо одно поднятие на уровень выше `../../`

Comment: Я правил код, посмотрите правильно же правил

Comment: у вас `css` читается?

Comment: да он читается кажется

Comment: тогда этот код внесите в `CSS` с `../` так как папки `CSS` и `IMAGES` находятся на одном уровне, или перенесите саму папку с изображениями в папка `CSS` тогда путь к ним будет таким как вы писали `background-image: url("images/home.jpg");`, тоже попробуйте написать без кавычек `background-image: url(images/home.jpg);`

Comment: Я добавил свой style.css там же все правильно написано?

Comment: лутше на `body` или добавить клас в body типа `<body class="bg-full">` который `bg-full { 
    background-image: url('../../images/home.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: добавил в пример `body`с класом

Comment: Я правил код для index и для style можете посмотреть

Comment: только перед `bg-full` точка должна быть `.bg-full` упустил. Когда вы в свойи шаблон вставляете  (не тут ) раюотает или нет ?

Comment: к сожалению нет(((

Comment: если сервер не выдает картинку ничего из преложенного не поможет